# Unable to launch a bat script with options

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I have a batch script (`script.bat`) that is supposed to launch a `jar`. Here is its content:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% -jar myJar.jar %*
```

In the options, I'm supposed to send two information:

1. The URL witch must be: login:password@host:port/protocol: -u URL
2. An input file: -i input

When I try the command: script.bat or script.bat -u, that shows some information indicating that required options are missing. But once I try the whole command, the following error occurs:

> script.bat not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I'm using Windows XP pro Version 2002 service pack 3

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Is the CMD path pointing to the folder that script.bat is stored in? i.e. `C:\Users\Me\Documents\SomeFolder\ ` If not you will have to use the full path instead of just `script.bat`

Comment: Well I resolved the issue.
Indeed, my script is called "server-client.bat" and the character "-" is not correctly written. It's hex value must be "2D" but in my case, I found the value "1F".

Thanks to all !

Comment: @user1379371 Cheers for finding this cause fast. You can post that as an actual answer and even mark your own answer as accepted, so the question does not keep floating around unanswered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was just a typo and it's not even show in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add an answer here :)
"Well I resolved the issue. Indeed, my script is called "server-client.bat" and the character "-" is not correctly written. It's hex value must be "2D" but in my case, I found the value "1F". Thanks to all !"